# Convert to DateTime Format

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting, datetime-format, typeconverter

Hello is there a way to convert this string "Saturday 04/23/2013 11:05 PM" to a valid DateTime Format?

Because it gives me FormatExceptionError everytime I execute this condition:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect.

```
if(DateTime.Parse("Saturday 04/23/2013 11:05 PM") < DateTime.Today)
{
//code here
}
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: It is hard to convert invalid value to valid one. You can do string manipulations... Can you simply reject invalid value?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Why will parse exact not work when we will give format also.

Comment: why is someone gving everyone -1?  Would you care to explain?

Comment: @Harrison post clearly states that date has invalid day of the week - looks like OP wants to convert invalid dates into some (randomly picked?) valid dates. Unfortunately there no comments from OP on the exact goal yet...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov So you are giving everyone who tries to help to OP a -1 because "you" believe the OP didn't formulate the question well?  He didn't clearly state  he wants to convert incorrect data to correct data. You made that "Ass-umption". He gave an example of bad data and wanted to know why he got a format exception and a solution.  Giving -1 to anyone who answers doesn't make the community want to give this OP help.  Please

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if you look at Nikhil Agrawal answer you can see the OP didn't actually know the date was invalid.

Comment: @Harrison It simply and obviously means that 04/23/2013 is a Tuesday not a Saturday and therefore the string the OP posted is NOT valid and therefore there is no way to convert this in exact matter as posted.

Comment: BTW replacing April(4) with March(3) would result in a correct date. Eventually a typo in the OP. `Saturday 03/23/2013 11:05 PM`is a correct date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `DateTime.ParseExact()`

```
string _strdate = "Tuesday 04/23/2013 11:05 PM"; // should be tuesday
DateTime _date = DateTime.ParseExact(_strdate,"dddd MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", 
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

- [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

---

[image]

Comment: Removed -1... Also now it is somewhat cheating - parse will handle valid date just fine... OP asked for invalid date for some reason :)

Comment: yeah. should be tuesday. sorry I forgot to change the dddd. xD

Comment: yes, that is why I also added links for custom date format `:)`

Answer (score 1):

If you expect invalid data you should use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) or [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)

```
DateTime myDate;
if(DateTime.TryParse("Saturday 04/23/2013 11:05 PM", out myDate))
{
   if (myDate < DateTime.Today) { //code here }
}
else
{
   //Do something here for invalid data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of **week was incorrect**.

04/23/2013 is Tuesday, not Saturday .

Maybe the exception occurs when your datetime statement is Contradiction.

Hope it help...

Answer (score 0):

The date and day of week do not match. 23rd April of 2013 is Tuesday and not Saturday. In no calendar of world you will have this day as Saturday. That's why it gives error **`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect.`**

So may be it converts your date and then validates. Hence it is failing in validation.

But when Tuesday is provided, This will work.

```
string str = "Tuesday 04/23/2013 11:05 PM";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dddd MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]

Comment: Hahaha. Yes Sorry! This helped me trace the problem. :)